Unable to Set Initial Value for access_token and token_expiry Variables from Pre-request Script when Running Postman Collection via CLI
I'm running into an issue with my Postman setup when executing collections through the Postman CLI . Specifically, I'm trying to dynamically set the access_token and token_expiry variables from a pre-request script before each request.
But it works fine while using running collection from postman GUI.
below ones are tried, but unable to resolve
pm.variables.set("access_token", newToken);
pm.variables.set("token_expiry", newExpiryTime);

and
pm.collectionVariables.set("access_token", newToken);
pm.collectionVariables.set("token_expiry", newExpiryTime);


Via a script, it would only populate the current value so that anything saved/store is not instantly synced and is only seen by you. Have you tried using pm.environment.set() and passing that id to the CLI with the -e flag?
